# How to add additional url type parameter in xcode?

Tags: flutter, xcode

Here I want to add additional url type parameter, it says click here, but it doesn't add it

[image: Here I want to add additional url type parameter, it says click here, but it doesn't add it]

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to add URLTypes by editing info.plist file of your project.

You can add by following

```xml
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <!-- Your other keys & values -->
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
              <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.*********</string>
        <string>additional URL type for same app.</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
  <!-- Add your additional URL type parameters here -->
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>My Other App</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myotherapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: So it is aligned the same as (dict) tag of CFBundleTypeRole, right?! but inside an array which makes related to the specific URL type

Answer (score 0):

To add an additional URL type parameter in Xcode, follow these steps:

1. Open the Xcode project that contains your app.
2. Select your app target in the Project Navigator.
3. Click the Info tab.
4. Scroll down to the URL Types section.
5. Click the + button to add a new URL type.
6. In the URL Types field, enter the URL scheme for your app.
7. In the Identifier field, enter a unique identifier for your URL type.
8. Click the Add button.
9. In the URL Schemes field for the new URL type, enter the additional URL type parameter.
10. Click the Save button.

For example, if your app's URL scheme is my-app and you want to add the additional URL type parameter param1, you would enter the following in the URL Schemes field for the new URL type:

Comment: Incompleted copy from chatGPT?